# How To POST Data from ESP826 to php file on xammpp server

Tags: php, esp8266

I am trying to POST data from a PicMicro 18F47K40 which is controlling a
Solar Tracker using a ESP8266.
I have updated the ESP8266:-
AT version:1.7.5.0(Oct  9 2021 09:26:04)
SDK version:3.0.5(b29dcd3)
compile time:Oct 15 2021 18:05:30

The problem is I cannot get it to post the data, all other commands work OK
I was trying originally with 8 variables but have now just setup a 2 field
Database to test it. Sending a POST from a browser using the same PHP files
it works OK.  But when sent from ESP8266 it comes up with "Undfined Array Key"
which is because the server is not reciveing the POST variable information.
This is the Commads sent:-

```
AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP","192.168.1.103",80\r\n
AT+CIPSEND=0,132\r\n
POST /insert.php, HTTP/1.1\r\n  
Host: 192.168.1.103\r\n         
User-Agent: Mozilla\r\n    
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n"]   
\r\n\r\n
Content-Length: 20\r\n     
\r\n\r\n                      
Col_1=,Dec Value1,&Col_2=,Dec Value2,\r\n\r\n    
\r\n\r\n
```

The response from ESP8266:-

```
AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP","192.168.1.103",80
0,CONNECT

OK
AT+CIPSEND=0,132

OK
> 

Recv 132 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,0,488:HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 18 May 2022 17:00:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/8.1.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.5
Location: http://192.168.1.103/
Content-Length: 254
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "Col_1" in <b>
          C:\xampp\htdocs\insert.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "Col_2" in <b>
          C:\xampp\htdocs\insert.php</b>    on line <b>18</b><br />
 record created successfully
0,CLOSED
```

It does access the PHP file and adds a record to the Database but
the field values are empty.

Obviously the command sequence is not correct or I have something wrong
any help or suggestions would be good, thank you.

Have modified code as suggested and attach php code, still has same error and no data in DB.

```
HSerOut ["POST /insert.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"]      
HSerOut ["Host: 192.168.1.103\r\n"]        
HSerOut ["User-Agent: Mozilla\r\n"]    
HSerOut ["Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"]
HSerOut ["\r\n"]   
HSerOut ["Content-Length: 19\r\n\r\n"]
HSerOut ["\r\n"]      
HSerOut ["Col_1=",Dec Value1,"&Col_2=",Dec Value2,"\r\n\r\n"]  
HSerOut ["\r\n"]

<?php
$servername = "192.168.1.103:3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "test_esp";
var_dump($_POST);
  // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

/* * Get data out of $_POST array
* and do a query to insert it into test_scores table *
*/ 
$Col_1 = $_POST['Col_1']; 
$Col_2 = $_POST['Col_2']; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO esp_table (Col_1, Col_2)
        VALUES ('" . $Col_1 . "', '" . $Col_2 . "')";
     
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo " record created successfully";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 
 $conn->close();

 }
```

var_dump() of the $_POST data = "array(0) {
}"

No input validation on the PHP side so I could see if it was accessing DB.
With Content Length removed makes no difference.

Comment: Show us the PHP code and a `var_dump()` of the `$_POST` data.

Comment: the data sent are not urlencoded

Comment: At a glance you've got far too many line breaks and trash data between the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers, and the `Content-Length` value is not correct and probably should not be statically defined. So long as the client device closes the connection after sending the data you should be able to get away with omitting the `Content-Length` header entirely if it's not possible to calculate the value.

Comment: And from the error message and vague description you've given it sounds like you are not doing any kind of input validation on the PHP side.

Comment: remove the `,` from `POST /insert.php, HTTP/1.1\r\n`

Comment: Still unable to get it working

Answer (score 0):

It needed a one line STRING of Headers+ Data, using several "Hserout" was the proplem. It added spaces which made the Headers unreadable or incorrect format for the xampp server.